# MySQL Server won't start

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql

Something seems to have happened with MySQL server (MariaDB dropped-in). If there is any needed information that I have not provided, please specify.

```
$ sudo service myql start
Failed to start myql.service: Unit myql.service not found.
```

```
$ whereis mysql
mysql: /etc/mysql /usr/share/mysql
```

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libmysql-java     5.1.38-1  all Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL
ii  mysql-common 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-server-core-5.7  5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64  MySQL database server binaries
ii  php-mysql 1:7.0+35ubuntu6 all MySQL module for PHP [default]    
ii  php7.0-mysql 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 MySQL module for PHP
```

Comment: You are missing the letter "s" in mysql start.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling a cat a cat, i.e. if you want to start MySql, you may get it to work like so:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

... instead of:

```
sudo service myql start
```

Credits: [stumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/users/767056/stumblebee), as per [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/998397/timeline#comment_1613296) below the question ...